# Parcelable encounteredClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object

Tags: java, android, serializable, parcelable

I've implemented a class that implements Serializable object.

```
public class SaveMe implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String someValue1;
    private String someValue2;
}
```

But whenever I try to use it in a Bundle, I get this exception:

```
 Parcelable encounteredClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object
     at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:1951)
     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1822)
     at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2008)
     at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:208)
     at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1034)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

Hm... Similar issue when using Parcelable:

```
Class not found when unmarshalling
```

Comment: Can you show the method call that causes the exception? I've had issues with serializable as well...

Comment: actually, it is b.putSerializable("savedinstance", new SaveMe()) where b is a Bundle object. Then it is called implicitly when bundle gets restored. Actually, it is restored from another application. Maybe this is an issue?

Comment: If your other app doesn't know the class SaveMe that would probably be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be running into class loader issues. You need to call setClassLoader() on the Bundle before you read serialized objects out of them.

Make sure you call `setClassLoader(SaveMe.class.getClassLoader())` before reading from the bundle.

If the compiler cannot find SaveMe when compiling then for sure that class is missing in the target application as [Damp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/525623/damp) suggested.

See this answer for more details:
[Parcelable inside bundle which is added to Parcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421582/parcelable-inside-bundle-which-is-added-to-parcel/13575442#13575442)