# Parcelable inside bundle which is added to Parcel

Tags: android, parcelable

In my project I have a model which holds basic information about model. For example lets say that the model is a Car. Then there are many different varieties of Cars and these have different data assigned to them. All models must be parcelables.

The differences between different cars is very small, it might just be a few data fields. So this is solved by creating presenters (just a class that holds data) for the different cars. The presenter would then know which extra data it should hold. Because the the presenter itself is not parcelable it will have a Bundle for all its data which then the Car class will then add to the parcelable. I don't want to make the presenters into parcelables.

So Car takes the Bundle from the presenter and puts it in its parcel:

```
  public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
    parcel.writeBundle(getPresenter().getBundle());
  }
```

And it will then unpack it with:

```
  public Car(Parcel parcel) {    
    getPresenter().setBundle(parcel.readBundle());
  }
```

This works fine until a parcelable object is added to the bundle by the presenter.
Then I get this error:

```
11-16 15:06:37.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15193): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-16 15:06:37.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15193): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.activity}: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.example.model.engine
11-16 15:06:37.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15193):         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2185)
11-16 15:06:37.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15193):         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
11-16 15:06:37.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15193):         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:142)
11-16 15:06:37.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15193):         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
11-16 15:06:37.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15193):         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-16 15:06:37.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15193):         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-16 15:06:37.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15193):         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
11-16 15:06:37.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15193):         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-16 15:06:37.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15193):         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-16 15:06:37.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15193):         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
11-16 15:06:37.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15193):         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
11-16 15:06:37.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15193):         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-16 15:06:37.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15193): Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.example.model.engine
11-16 15:06:37.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15193):         at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2077)
11-16 15:06:37.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15193):         at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1965)
11-16 15:06:37.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15193):         at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2226)
11-16 15:06:37.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15193):         at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
11-16 15:06:37.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15193):         at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1055)
11-16 15:06:37.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15193):         at com.example.cars.CarPresenter.getExtraString(CarPresenter.java:34)
11-16 15:06:37.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15193):         ... 11 more
```

So it somehow fails to read anything from the Bundle.

This can be solved by modifying the readBundle call to:

```
  public Car(Parcel parcel) {    
    getPresenter().setBundle(parcel.readBundle(engine.class.getClassLoader()));
  }
```

However, wouldn't this mean that I could only have one type of parcelables in my bundle? For example, what if another presenter wanted to add another parcelable object to the bundle?

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You wrote in a comment:

> However, my question was ment to be more of why do I even have to specify a class loader in this case

Dianne Hackborn, Android framework engineer, [writes](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/QFjqaD_5470) that:

> when the bundle reads from the parcel it just extracts the data.  It doesn't actually unparcel from that data until later when you retrieve stuff from the bundle.

In the [Bundle source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/os/Bundle.java), we see that the `setClassLoader()`method sets the field `mClassLoader`:

```
public void setClassLoader(ClassLoader loader) {
     mClassLoader = loader;
 }
```

If we don't use `setClassLoader()` or the constructor `Bundle(ClassLoader loader)`,the `mClassLoader` field will be set to the default `ClassLoader`:

```
public Bundle(int capacity) {
     //...
     mClassLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
 }
```

`mClassLoader` is then used to unmarshal the parcelled data in the `unparcel()` method:

```
 mParcelledData.readMapInternal(mMap, N, mClassLoader);
 mParcelledData.recycle();
 mParcelledData = null;
```

Net, if you don't set the `ClassLoader` it will default to the system `ClassLoader` when unmarshalling its parcelled data, and we'll get a `ClassNotFoundException` when unmarshalling our custom `Parcelable` object data,

Comment: I know the basics of parcels, and it is working everywhere else in my app. Engine does implement Parcelable. The problem is that if I put a parcelable in a bundle, and then the bundle in a parcel, I am not able to unpack the parcelable form the bundle (or any other field in the bundle).

Comment: Yes, I have tried that and I think it did not work. However, my question was ment to be more of why do I even have to specify a class loader in this case.

Comment: But you still don't actually answer the question. Why do you have to specify a custom classloader, why can't the system classloader load the class?

Answer (score 20):

ClassLoaders are one of the least understood features of Java. They provide "Namespaces", and in fact those namespaces can "nest" by virtue of the fact that if a class is not found by the current ClassLoader it can check a "Parent" ClassLoader.

In the case of an Android application there are two ClassLoaders. There is one which knows how to load classes from your APK and one that knows how to load classes from the Android framework. The former has the latter set as the "Parent" class loader so in general you don't notice. However, since Bundle is a framework class, and is loaded by the framework class loader you need to tell it about the ClassLoader being used to find classes in your APK. The class loader that Bundle uses by default is the framework ClassLoader which is a "lower" namespace than the one with your APK classes in it.

So by telling the bundle which ClassLoader to use you are telling it that it needs to check the APK ClassLoader for classes. It defaults to checking the framework APK since that is the ClassLoader which loaded the Bundle class, and is thus the only "Namespace" it knows how to find classes in.

Answer (score 5):

You wrote:

> This can be solved by modifying the readBundle call to:
>
> `public Car(Parcel parcel) {`
>           `getPresenter().setBundle(parcel.readBundle(engine.class.getClassLoader()));`
>   `}`
>
> However, wouldn't this mean that I could only have one type of
>   parcelables in my bundle? For example, what if another presenter
>   wanted to add another parcelable object to the bundle?

Actually, no. When you set the classLoader to `engine.class.getClassLoader()`, you are actually providing a class loader that knows how to load all classes from your APK. So you can use the same classloader to unparcel all other custom classes in your application that implement Parcelable.

The problem you are seeing is that, when you **don't** specify a classloader, the (default) system class loader is used to unparcel the `Bundle`. The system class loader only knows how to load classes that are known to the Android system and doesn't know how to load any application-specific classes.

Just to clarify, (in general) there isn't a "class loader per class", there is a system class loader and then there is a "class loader per application". I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score -4):

This is my Model which implements Parcelable:

```
public class ProgramModel implements Parcelable
{
    private int id = -1;
    private String title = "";
    private String time = "";
    private String day = "";
    private String organization = "";
    private String participants = "";
    private String description = "";
    private String descriptionFull = "";
    private String location = "";
    private String locationCaption = "";
    private int locationCode = 0;
    private String locationMap = "";
    private String imageUrl = "";
    private String color = "";
    private int colorId = -1;
    private int columnId = -1;
    private String startTime = "";
    private String endTime = "";
    private Date convertedTimeStart = null;
    private Date convertedTimeEnd = null;
    private String theme = "";
    private ArrayList<TagModel> tags = new ArrayList<TagModel>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> tagsId = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public ProgramModel()
    {
    }

    private ProgramModel(Parcel in)
    {
        id = in.readInt();
        title = in.readString();
        time = in.readString();
        day = in.readString();
        organization = in.readString();
        participants = in.readString();
        description = in.readString();
        descriptionFull = in.readString();
        location = in.readString();
        locationCaption = in.readString();
        locationCode = in.readInt();
        locationMap = in.readString();
        imageUrl = in.readString();
        color = in.readString();
        colorId = in.readInt();
        columnId = in.readInt();
        startTime = in.readString();
        endTime = in.readString();
        convertedTimeStart = new Date(in.readLong());
        convertedTimeEnd = new Date(in.readLong());
        theme = in.readString();
        in.readTypedList(tags, TagModel.CREATOR);
        in.readList(tagsId, Integer.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // Other getters and setters

    @Override
    public int describeContents()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // this is used to regenerate your object
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ProgramModel> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ProgramModel>()
    {
        public ProgramModel createFromParcel(Parcel in)
        {
            return new ProgramModel(in);
        }

        public ProgramModel[] newArray(int size)
        {
            return new ProgramModel[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags)
    {
        out.writeInt(id);
        out.writeString(title);
        out.writeString(time);
        out.writeString(day);
        out.writeString(organization);
        out.writeString(participants);
        out.writeString(description);
        out.writeString(descriptionFull);
        out.writeString(location);
        out.writeString(locationCaption);
        out.writeInt(locationCode);
        out.writeString(locationMap);
        out.writeString(imageUrl);
        out.writeString(color);
        out.writeInt(colorId);
        out.writeInt(columnId);
        out.writeString(startTime);
        out.writeString(endTime);
        out.writeLong(convertedTimeStart.getTime());
        out.writeLong(convertedTimeEnd.getTime());
        out.writeString(theme);
        out.writeTypedList(tags);
        out.writeList(tagsId);
    }
}
```

Write data into intent in Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("ProgramModel", programDetailsModel);
startActivity(intent);
```

Read data from bundle in Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        fromBundleModel = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("ProgramModel");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a lot of models which implements parcelable... this gives me nothing new.